# Is there a way to remove everything after the last dash in certain column names?

Tags: python, pandas

```
g_20_tomato g_34_lettuce g_60_carrot price
10          24           45          11
34          47           27          77
```

I have the following example dataframe.  I want to remove everything after the last hyphen for the columns that contain 'g_'.

I tried this:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[:-1].str.join('_'), inplace= True)
```

This gave me: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Answer (score 0):

You can actually directly apply string operations to `df.columns`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_[^_]+$', '', regex=True)
```

or:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', 1).str[0]
```

With `rename` you can pass a function and the values are evaluated **as string**:

```
df.rename(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0], axis=1)
```

output:

```
   g_20  g_34  g_60  price
0    10    24    45     11
1    34    47    27     77
```